# maya.standalone.initialize() hangs forever

Tags: python, maya

Steps to repeat:

```
gfixler@gigabox:/autodesk/maya2012-x64/bin$ ./mayapy
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Nov  3 2009, 14:09:42) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20070626 (Red Hat 4.1.2-14)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import maya.standalone
>>> maya.standalone.initialize() # this hangs until I ^C
^CResult: untitled
Fatal Error. Attempting to save in /usr/tmp/gfixler.20120908.1953.ma
gfixler@gigabox:/autodesk/maya2012-x64/bin$
```

I think it's a library path issue of some sort, but I don't know how to find out.

Comment: In your case, Maya's default installation path is /usr/autodesk/maya2012-x64. Try update the path or make a symbolic link.

Comment: You had me investigate this, and it turns out I haven't noticed that /autodesk is a symlink to /usr/autodesk. I knew they both existed, but didn't realize they were both the same. That simplifies things a bit. However, no amount of adding paths to sys.path would help. I did solve it though, after about 45 minutes of fighting with it just now. I'll post my solution as an answer, for posterity. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue.

In trying to solve this I learned about `python -m trace --trace script.py`, and also a bit about pdb, a Python debugger. I tied these together by calling a trace on a file containing this:

```
pdb.run(maya.standalone.initialize(), globals(), locals())
```

I don't know if that was using either incorrectly, or overkill (trace alone was hanging after printing out a tremendous amount of information, which redirected into a file yielded nothing useful), but after hitting `n` (next) and `s` (step) followed by hundreds of enter keypresses in pdb got me nowhere, on a whim I typed `help` and got a help menu. I decided to try the listed EOF command, and it ran until it crashed with a message about being unable to load the commandPort. I remembered I set that value to autoload (Preferences window, Applications section) last week while fighting with nose, and apparently that was causing it to hang on a bad entry (":12345"), with absolutely no messages about anything. I opened UI Maya, deleted that preference, and now `mayapy` initializes fine. Phwew.